# python code to get ending brace index from list

Tags: python, text-parsing

I have my input list of strings where I need to pass the index of any opening brace and expecting my python function to return its corresponding closing brace's index and its value.

Input list :

```
mylist=[
'a',
'b(',
'(',
'cd',
'd(e)',
'hi)',
'last brace) '
]
```

I need get the index and the string of the list

```
getindex=func(mylist[2])
```

getindex should have `hi)` with index 5. It should ignore any corresponding balanced braces inbetween ex: `d(e)` or the `last brace)` ,etc.

```
getindex=(5,'hi)')
```

I am little new to python and appreciate your time in help me.Thanks!

Comment: Please put your codes for us to see your needs.

Comment: You need to start by rethinking the design of your function. `mylist[2]` is just the string `"("`, how will your function know the index of the starting point? There can easily be multiple `"("` elements in your list. For that matter, how will it know what list to search in? A better "signature" is `func(mylist, 2)`. I'd go with that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my text file, I already know the opening brace is of single character is '(' and I am picking up the first occurance of '(' and has no other character. I am ok to pass either func(mylist[2]) or func(mylist, 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to count the left brace start from start line, when meet left brace, increase it, when meet right brace, decrease it. when it reach zero again, you find the correct index.

Sample code for you:

```
def get_closing_brace_index(str_list, left_idx):
    # input check, you can ignore it if you assure valid input
    if left_idx < 0 or left_idx >= len(str_list) or '(' not in str_list[left_idx]:
        return -1, ''

    # use a left brace counter
    left_count = 0
    # just ignore everything before open_brace_index
    for i, s in enumerate(str_list[left_idx:]):
        for c in s:
            if c == '(':
                left_count += 1
            elif c == ')':
                left_count -= 1
                # find matched closing brace
                if left_count == 0:
                    return i + left_idx, str_list[i + left_idx]
                # invalid brace match
                elif left_count < 0:
                    return -1, ''
    return -1, ''

def test():
    mylist = [
        'a',
        'b(',
        '(',
        'cd',
        'd(e)',
        'hi)',
        'last brace) '
    ]

    print(get_closing_brace_index(mylist, 1))
    # output (6, 'last brace) ')
    print(get_closing_brace_index(mylist, 2))
    # output (5, 'hi)')
    print(get_closing_brace_index(mylist, 4))
    # output (4, 'd(e)')
    print(get_closing_brace_index(mylist, 0))
    # output (-1, '')
    print(get_closing_brace_index(mylist, 6))
    # output (-1, '')
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: Awesome!. Thanks a lot recnac@. This works I will try to use this code and raise exception in case if it returns -1.

Comment: this will fail when a test case has two `((` in it and you you need to find the index in that case

Comment: Vick seems mention 'I am picking up the first occurance of '(' ' @prashantrana

Comment: it's better to implement it using a queue , start from the 0 find all opening and closing pair index, provide answer then

Comment: for more complex problems, `stack` is better solution, but it is simple, just a counter can handle it, and it is faster : ) @prashantrana

Comment: @recnac for this small set it's ok, but for large set (10^5 +) list length , stack is better solution for that